# what is the meaning of 都不甘于平庸 in the song 致你 by 苡慧?

Tags: mandarin, songs

The line 都不甘于平庸 seems to be speaking of a degree of confidence, and a will to demonstrate it.

But the lines before and after it, don't seem to support this interpretation.

How is it best to read this line?

The relevant lines are below.

```
恋恋不舍又念念不忘
被汹涌浪潮淹没
覆盖了属于我
最孤独的海洋
迷茫的 游荡
不知去往何方
支离破碎
或遍体鳞伤
研磨成匆匆过往
一幕幕的相逢
都不甘于平庸
原谅我 此番
不经意的设防
跌跌宕宕
你占据我的遐想
封上你路过的窗
你的声音
来来往往
穿梭在无人演出的剧场
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the song is from the narrative point of the singer, expressing her anxieties, but the subject of the verb phrase "都不甘于平庸" (all unwilling to be mediocre) is not the singer, but 一幕幕的相逢 (the **encountering scenes** that came one after another)

- [一幕幕的相逢都不甘于平庸] = [所有的場景都不甘平凡]
- [Scenes of encountering are not willing to be mediocre] = [all the encounters are unwilling to be ordinary]
- the subject is not "**I**" (the anxious one) but "**the encounters**" (personification)

In other words, those encounters have powerfully impacted the narrator